# Is there a way to document what the value of `this` is in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is there a way to document what the value of `this` will (or must) be in the body of a function?

An example of such a function might be an event handler that is attached to a DOM node. I might define the handling function elsewhere and I want to be able to document that `this` will be the target node.

`@param` doesn't seem to cut it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... and seconds after posting the question, I thought: maybe it's just `@this` and lo! and behold: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-this.html